# Can I update Direct3D?

Tags: directx, nvidia-quadro, xeon, direct3d

When I try to open NBA2K17 game, there is a window with some information:

> "Graphics card with DirectX 10.0 feature set or lower detected. This application requires Direct3D 11 installed, running a GPU with Direct3D 10.1 feature set or greater, and a Dual Core CPU or better, with SSE3 support or greater."

I have:

- processor: Intel Xeon X5650
- graphics card: nVidia Quadro FX 1800
- 8 GB of RAM

I have DirectX 12 on my computer. My graphics card has DirectX 11, but it has Direct3D 10. Intel Xeon X5650 supports SSE3.

So my questions are:

1. Can I update Direct3D?
2. and how can I play the game?

Answer (score 1):

Direct3d is the primary graphics handling portion of DirectX. This means that your DirectX version matches your Direct3d version. Your graphics card doesn't have DirectX 11 support, as seen [here](http://www.nvidia.com/object/product_quadro_fx_1800_us.html). And thus, you can't update your DirectX version.